# Add a .xml GDAL basemap layer to a raster base R plot

Tags: r, plot, maps, geospatial, raster

I have a dataset comprised of latitude, longitude, and values (the lat/lon for the southern Ontario). I've converted the dataset to raster using rasterFromXYZ (raster package) and I'm able to plot the data using the base R plot function. The data and code to rasterize and plot is below.

What I'm trying to do is add a basemap to the plot. I have a .XML GDAL basemap (Google Maps Layer) from https://felix.rohrba.ch/en/2016/awesome-basemap-layer-for-your-qgis-project/#google, but I can't figure out how to incorporate that into my existing code. I understand this is probably possible using ggplot but I'd like to avoid using ggplot.

```
df <- structure(c(-82.375002345, -81.291669055, -79.875002445, -80.291669095, 
            -80.541669085, -79.375002465, -78.875002485, -76.541669245, -75.708335945, 
            -82.208335685, -79.041669145, -79.625002455, -82.541669005, -82.375002345, 
            -80.291669095, -80.791669075, -80.208335765, -79.458335795, -80.958335735, 
            -79.708335785, -79.458335795, -80.125002435, -78.291669175, -77.375002545, 
            -75.708335945, -74.708335985, -81.458335715, -81.041669065, -81.208335725, 
            -78.541669165, -80.291669095, -79.708335785, -81.708335705, -79.125002475, 
            -77.291669215, -76.375002585, -80.708335745, -82.125002355, -81.625002375, 
            -81.708335705, -81.625002375, -80.958335735, -78.291669175, -77.791669195, 
            -78.708335825, -80.458335755, -79.958335775, -80.958335735, -79.791669115, 
            -79.541669125, -75.125002635, -74.625002655, -76.125002595, -79.291669135, 
            -77.875002525, -76.041669265, -79.625002455, -79.541669125, -81.375002385, 
            -81.125002395, -80.208335765, -80.625002415, -81.375002385, -81.791669035, 
            -78.625002495, -79.791669115, -75.625002615, -77.125002555, -77.125002555, 
            -77.541669205, -80.375002425, -79.875002445, -78.791669155, -78.541669165, 
            -79.958335775, -79.958335775, -75.875002605, -75.291669295, -74.625002655, 
            -74.125002675, -79.458335795, -79.291669135, -79.958335775, -79.791669115, 
            -80.458335755, -83.041668985, -82.958335655, -79.708335785, -79.541669125, 
            -79.375002465, -79.291669135, -79.041669145, -79.208335805, -79.375002465, 
            -79.875002445, -80.208335765, -76.458335915, -75.625002615, -81.208335725, 
            -79.208335805, -79.291669135, -79.208335805, -79.625002455, -80.375002425, 
            -79.958335775, -79.791669115, -80.625002415, -81.125002395, -79.625002455, 
            -76.958335895, -75.791669275, -75.541669285, -80.708335745, -80.458335755, 
            -82.208335685, -81.875002365, -81.125002395, -80.375002425, -81.375002385, 
            -82.458335675, -82.875002325, -81.958335695, -80.791669075, -77.708335865, 
            -79.208335805, -80.041669105, -80.875002405, -82.958335655, -79.125002475, 
            -79.375002465, -81.125002395, -78.375002505, -76.375002585, -75.791669275, 
            42.958333255, 42.958333255, 43.208333245, 43.124999915, 43.458333235, 
            43.624999895, 43.874999885, 44.208333205, 45.458333155, 42.374999945, 
            43.124999915, 42.874999925, 42.041666625, 42.624999935, 42.791666595, 
            43.124999915, 43.541666565, 43.874999885, 44.541666525, 44.374999865, 
            44.624999855, 43.874999885, 44.291666535, 44.208333205, 44.624999855, 
            45.041666505, 43.374999905, 44.124999875, 42.791666595, 45.041666505, 
            43.374999905, 43.458333235, 42.708333265, 44.124999875, 44.458333195, 
            45.458333155, 42.874999925, 42.874999925, 42.958333255, 43.708333225, 
            44.208333205, 43.708333225, 43.958333215, 44.291666535, 44.374999865, 
            44.541666525, 43.041666585, 43.374999905, 43.708333225, 44.124999875, 
            45.291666495, 45.291666495, 45.124999835, 45.041666505, 45.041666505, 
            44.874999845, 43.624999895, 43.208333245, 44.458333195, 44.708333185, 
            44.124999875, 43.958333215, 43.874999885, 43.208333245, 44.124999875, 
            44.041666545, 45.041666505, 45.791666475, 44.041666545, 44.124999875, 
            43.708333225, 43.541666565, 44.624999855, 44.541666525, 44.541666525, 
            44.791666515, 45.291666495, 45.541666485, 45.624999815, 45.374999825, 
            43.708333225, 43.708333225, 43.291666575, 43.291666575, 43.541666565, 
            42.291666615, 42.208333285, 43.791666555, 43.791666555, 43.958333215, 
            43.874999885, 43.874999885, 43.791666555, 43.791666555, 43.374999905, 
            43.041666585, 44.291666535, 45.374999825, 43.041666585, 43.208333245, 
            43.124999915, 42.958333255, 44.291666535, 43.458333235, 43.458333235, 
            43.458333235, 44.291666535, 44.291666535, 45.041666505, 44.291666535, 
            45.374999825, 45.458333155, 43.374999905, 42.624999935, 42.624999935, 
            42.541666605, 43.291666575, 43.041666585, 43.541666565, 42.291666615, 
            42.291666615, 43.041666585, 42.708333265, 45.458333155, 45.291666495, 
            45.374999825, 44.624999855, 42.374999945, 43.041666585, 44.708333185, 
            42.958333255, 44.374999865, 44.208333205, 44.541666525, 0.669870978, 
            0.492866346, 0.767528706, 1.97604309, 1.362630486, 3.236438142, 
            2.027923758, 2.500953378, 0.642404742, 0.89265267, 3.358510302, 
            2.11337427, 1.081864518, 0.727855254, 1.081864518, 0.730907058, 
            1.329060642, 1.734950574, 1.844815518, 1.176470442, -0.395208618, 
            0.260929242, 1.28938719, 2.702372442, 2.92210233, 2.488746162, 
            0.965895966, 0.019836726, 0.639352938, -1.490806254, 1.759365006, 
            1.493858058, 0.520332582, -0.126649866, 1.643396454, 0.172426926, 
            0.978103182, 0.532539798, 0.660715566, 2.320896942, 2.363622198, 
            0.956740554, 2.671854402, 1.551842334, 0.093080022, 0.962844162, 
            0.761425098, 1.33516425, 1.62508563, 1.231402914, 1.551842334, 
            1.658655474, 0.95368875, -0.383001402, -0.51117717, 2.351414982, 
            1.70138073, 1.536583314, 2.061493602, 1.951628658, 0.242618418, 
            -0.904859886, 1.637292846, 0.398260422, 0.96894777, 1.368734094, 
            2.08285623, -1.039139262, 2.870221662, 2.824444602, 0.462348306, 
            1.951628658, -0.914015298, -0.517280778, 0.682078194, 0.917067102, 
            0.733958862, 0.86213463, 0.050354766, 0.72480345, 0.944533338, 
            1.902799794, 0.852979218, 1.70138073, 1.383993114, 1.246661934, 
            1.16731503, 1.68612171, 2.09811525, 1.454184606, 2.092011642, 
            2.543678634, 2.049286386, 1.374837702, 1.22835111, 0.978103182, 
            2.31174153, 0.630197526, 0.569161446, 3.370717518, 3.086899746, 
            2.870221662, 0.96894777, 1.683069906, 1.499961666, 2.256809058, 
            0.505073562, 1.71663975, -0.16021971, 2.320896942, 0.752269686, 
            0.630197526, 1.451132802, 0.758373294, 0.431830266, 0.517280778, 
            1.54879053, 1.515220686, 1.557945942, 0.98420679, 1.170366834, 
            0.337224342, 0.520332582, -0.947585142, -0.581368662, 0.550850622, 
            2.058441798, 1.393148526, 3.016708254, -0.379949598, 0.410467638, 
            0.29755089, 2.52536781, 3.08995155), dim = c(134L, 3L), dimnames = list(
              NULL, c("lon", "lat", "value")))

raster <- rasterFromXYZ(df)
col_ramp <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "lightblue", "pink", "red"))
cuts <- pretty(df[,3], n = 16)
col_ramp_count <- length(cuts)

plot(raster, breaks = cuts, col = col_ramp(col_ramp_count), 
     ylab = "Latitude", xlab = "Longitude", main = "Temperature for Southern Ontario, Lake Ontario")
```

Comment: These xml files are small, and simply specify the type, bounding box and projection for the map. They also contain the url from which ArcGIS downloads the actual map as a raster image.  They don't contain the actual map data. You would simply plot the image, then draw your raster data over the top of it.